# How to add HTTPS on the EBS link on aws?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group

I have deployed my frontend in S3 bucket. backend is on EBS. bucket is secured with https but backend api's are not so frontend is not able to connect with the api's. i wanted to add HTTPS for the api's on EBS. i have generated Certificate for the domain name also. i have created a load balancer for the ec2 where my api's are deployed but still i'm not able to connect with it. i have set the Security groups groups also which routes the traffic from port 80 to 443. i don't know where i'm doing wrong or which step i'm missing.
Need help to know the full process and how this all mess is connected with each other.

Comment: can you check if the errors are about cross origin ?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your load balancer configuration, where you have identified port mappings?

Comment: error is cross origin only. frontend is in https so it not calling the unsecure http path

Comment: hey @matesio i have made the https port open which is 443 and also routed the traffic from http tp https which is port 80 to port 443 through load balancer. and now the backend (ebs) link stopped working too

Comment: What are your instance ports ?

Comment: port 443 and port 80. i have generated a cert with domain and after that i doesn't know how i can add this cert to my ec2 instance or EBS